# Using LCD and other modules with external regulated source and common ground

Tags: circuit-design, ground, grounding

I am designing a circuit where I want to interface various modules with Arduino Mega. The way I want to do it is use an external regulated power source for the individual modules, instead of powering the devices through the microcontroller.

For understanding purposes, I am using a 16x2 HD44780 LCD as an example, as shown in the image below. I am following the method of grounding, as explained in this [link](http://www.thebox.myzen.co.uk/Tutorial/Power_Supplies.html), where grounds of different source are connected together.

However, in my case I am powering the Arduino Mega through an LM2596 buck converter, which is connected to a 12 V supply and outputs 7-7.5 V. The output of the LM2596 is further regulated through a 7805 to supply the LCD with 5 V.

Since the power source for the Arduino Mega and LCD are the same, do we have to connect the Arduino pin GND to the 7805's GND, as highlighted in the image?

[image: Arduino Common ground]

PS. I am powering the Arduino through the DC jack, that's why I have shown a single connection to the microcontroller.

Comment: 7V is to low, go to 7.5V as minimum, I typically use about 8. The 7805 is going to give you a lot of grief, it needs decoupling and bulk capacitors connected to it. Check the data sheet and when they give you a maximum lead length to the cap that is very important do not exceed it. For the second voltage why not just use another Buck regulator, by the time you are finished it will be the cheapest and probably the most reliably.

Comment: The 7805 output is shorted to ground. No bueno.

Comment: Thanks @Gil and @ Rodo for bringing to notice about decoupling caps on 7805's input and output

Comment: You are very welcome. Be careful some of the buck, boost, and SEPIC regulators; not all have input and output "grounds" connected together. Yours should be OK. You need to be sure if you connect the input ground to the system ground otherwise no problem. You can get little switching 5V regulators that are not much bigger then the TO220 case (mounted on a PCB with leads) and they have all the caps needed on board. The efficiencies are in the 90% range. The 7805 dissipates all the excess energy as heat (Voltage Drop * current).

Answer (score 1):

Of course the grounds have to be connected.

Nothing works without a return path for currents, or reference voltage between two circuits.